# Awaiting two asynchronous commands in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So for example, lets say I have this code:

```
var cmd = require('node-cmd')


function getStuff() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var dataNStuff;
        cmd.get('brew --version', data => {
            dataNStuff += data;
        })

        cmd.get('yarn global ls', data => {
            dataNStuff += data;
        })
        resolve(dataNStuff)

    })
}
```

In this case cmd.get() is async, so I don't know when the data is coming in. I want to be able to have both calls already have the data come in before I `resolve(dataNStuff)`, is this even possible with a Promise, and no I do not want to use a callback in this scenario. Is there a much simpler or faster way of doing the exact same thing?

Comment: `Promise.all` is what you want

Comment: explain @JaromandaX

Comment: I will, but I'm wondering if Promises are necessarily the best option

Comment: are there other alternatives to promises and callbacks?

Comment: Yes that is the point, dataNStuff will be undefined when this code runs.

Comment: This is the worst part of javascript. It'll be fixed in ES7 with async/await. until then you have to write callback/promise messes (or use a transpiler)

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar - async/await does not obviate the need to understand async calling and, in fact works no better than plain promises.  All it really does is save a small bit of typing.  And, you STILL have to use something like promises with it.  So, there's no grand fix in ES7 that lets you write code without understanding async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Promises for the solution, use Promise.all, and "promisified" version of cmd.get

```
var cmd = require('node-cmd');

var cmdPromise = arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => cmd.get(arg, resolve));

function getStuff() {
    return Promise.all([cmdPromise('brew --version'), cmdPromise('yarn global ls')])
    .then(results => results.join(''));
}
```

to "explain" cmdPromise in case that compact version isn't readable, it's basically this:

```
var cmdPromise = function cmdPromise(arg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cmd.get(arg, data => resolve(data));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straightforward solution involving Promises.

```
function getStuff() { 
   var dataNStuff = '';
   var promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       cmd.get('brew --version', data => {
            dataNStuff += data;
            resolve();
        });
   });       
   var promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       cmd.get('yarn global ls', data => {
            dataNStuff += data;
            resolve();
        });
   });  
   return Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(function() {
       return dataNStuff;
   });   
}
```

I assume that `cmd.get` will execute one after the other. If this assumption is incorrect, then there is no guarantee of the order of the strings. (ie It may display brew before yarn or it may display yarn before brew.)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I've fixed it now. Scary to think it would have worked just fine regardless.

Comment: if you `resolve(data)`, then concatentate results in the `.then` you *can* guarantee order of results in the string :p (see my answer)

Comment: Andrew, is this really a good solution? I would not recommend using variables in the enclosing scope of promises. The accepted solution above is the way to go. Or do I miss some point?

Comment: @Stefan I do agree that the accepted solution should be the preferred approach. However, this solution would work, given the stated assumptions about ordering. Is there a reason you would not recommend using variables in the enclosing scope of promises?

Comment: In simple use cases like this, their is no problem. I did this by myself some days ago to acumulate results from database queries. Later, things got more envolved and errors where creeping in the code. Resorting to a pure Promise solution made code cleaner and easy to modify. I think promises with side effects should be avoided, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**ES2017 answer**: removing the `.then()` in favor of `=` via [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (as the comment from @stephen-bugs-kamenar mentions.

```
var log = console.log;

var getBanana = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('banana')
        }, 2000);
    });
}

var getGrape = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('grape')
        }, 3000);
    });
}

var start = async function(){
    var result = await Promise.all([getBanana(), getGrape(), 'apple'])
    console.log('All done', result)
}

start();
```